# Vue: Properties/data of mixin is not available when defining properties/data

Tags: typescript, vue.js, mixins, vue-mixin, vue-property-decorator

I have a vue mixin that stores information (`world` in below example), I'd like to access in several vue components, without explicitly importing it every time.

Here's the example:

```
<template>
  <ol>
    <li>Hello {{ world }}</li>
    <li>{{ greeting }}</li>
    <li>{{ greeting2 }}</li>
  </ol>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Mixins, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
class MyMixin extends Vue {
  world = 'world'
}

@Component
export default class Home extends Mixins(Vue, MyMixin) {
  greeting = 'Hello ' + this.world
  greeting2 = ''

  created() {
    this.greeting2 = 'Hello ' + this.world
  }
}
</script>
```

The page shows:

```
1. Hello world
2. Hello undefined
3. Hello world
```

Why is 2nd not working? Is this by design? Any better idea to circumvent that than 3.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to mixins this is by the design of classes, a property doesn't know the other one in declaration, but you could define `greeting` as computed property :

```
@Component
export default class Home extends Mixins(Vue, MyMixin) {

   greeting2 = ''
   
   get greeting (){
      return 'Hello ' + this.world
    }
  created() {
    this.greeting2 = 'Hello ' + this.world
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have a lot of properties in the mixin. The idea of the mixin was to avoid to import all of them. Writing a computed property for each of them, is almost as tedious ;-)

Comment: please edit this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/82l5889ko8?file=/components/Greet.vue) by providing the right version and give me the link